# Bouncing tubes not behaving

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

This is an animation question.

1. I have made a chrome tube, and set the Active Rigid Body settings for it to bounce on a concrete floor (passive Rigid Body) once or twice, then settle and stop rolling. (1.3 feet diameter, 19 feet length, mass = 8lbs., Shape: Cylinder, Friction: .5, Bounciness: 0, Collision Margin: 1.6)
2. I then duplicated it 15 times. However, some of the duplicates, despite having the same settings and belonging to the same Rigid Body World, and applying the transformation (adjusting x/y/z coordinates and size) do not behave the same way. They bounce like they're on steroids, and some of them fall through the concrete floor. The ones that stay on the surface refuse to stop rolling despite working with the friction settings.

I need them to stop bouncing, stop rolling after about 3 seconds (24fps), and then I'll proceed with the next part: changing shape.

Floor settings: 
Type: Passive; Shape: Mesh; Source: Base; Friction: 1.5; Margin: 1.575; Bounciness: 0

EDIT 10-27-16
Thanks for your suggestion. The floor has 100 subdivisions. Tubes #1 - #4 have 50 subdivisions.

I turned on the Copy Attributes Add-On. This allows the familiar Copy/Paste, and includes all attributes or selections as available. It performs better than the Duplicate for this animation. NONE of the copied/pasted tubes have the bouncing problem, or the falling through the floor problem. 
However, getting them to stop rolling is tricky. It seems to involve a careful tweak of the **Friction** and the **Bounciness** and the **Collision Margin** settings.

The number of tubes will be tripled to 15 for the next version. That seems to greatly change how they interact and bounce.

Comment: are the floor and tubes subdivided enough?

Comment: If you can't solve this as I couldn't in another app, I finished up abandoning the physics engine and emulated the bounces with plain ol'  keyframes.  Looked convincing too.  The extra objects were just duplicates of the first "AFTER" I'd done the bouncing keyframes.  Their individual animation Keyframes were then offset a little from each other to give them individuality.